# List with range of values of given length

Tags: python

I want to give paramters `valueFrom`, `valueTo` and `length.out`. The same how `seq` function works in R:

```
seq(0, 1, length.out = 5)
```

> 0.00 0.25 0.50 0.75 1.00

How to do it in python?

Is the only solution is:

```
range(valueFrom, valueTo, by=(valueTo - ValueFrom)/(lengthOut - valueTo - ValueFrom)) ?
```

Python is really messy language in compare with R or Java.

Comment: see np.linspace() in numpy module

Comment: "Python is really messy language in compare with R or Java" - I think otherwise my good sir

Comment: Indeed @Jaba, same

Comment: Although the only error in my comment is I am assuming OP's gender. *(hope I'm right)*

Comment: In python even I can't use letters like `ć` in comments !!! ERROR `SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xe6'`. Python is really awkward.

Comment: @stakowerflol it's usually frowned upon to comment code in any other language than English

Comment: @stakowerflol you absolutely can. What editor are you using? What encoding is the source file saved in? See the first two paragraphs in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23092402/4570170).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use NumPy module, it has many useful functions

```
import numpy as np
print(np.linspace(0, 1, 5))
```

Answer (score 2):

In python you can use [`np.arange`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) for this:

```
import numpy as np
np.arange(0,1.25,0.25)
array([0.  , 0.25, 0.5 , 0.75, 1.  ])
```

Or if you want to create a sequence by specifying its length use [`np.linspace`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html):

```
np.linspace(0,1,5)
array([0.  , 0.25, 0.5 , 0.75, 1.  ])
```

Comment: Note that the OP wants to specify the length of the sequence, not the step